# Using DLookup with combobox selection

Tags: vba, ms-access

I keep getting

> Datatype Mismatch

when I use the code I read off of another post. I will be posting every variation that I have tried I need this to lookup the value in a summary query so when you try and make a transaction when it is low it will show the popup saying your stock is low.

First Attempt below returns data mismatch.

```
Private Sub cboTransactionItem_AfterUpdate()

Dim Restock As Variant
Dim ReorderAmount As Variant

ReorderAmount = DLookup("'[Reorder Amount]'", "ReorderingStock", "[Transaction Item] = '" & Me!cboTransactionItem.Text & "'")
Restock = DLookup([True Stock], "ReorderingStock", "[Transaction Item] = '" & Me!cboTransactionItem.Text & "'")

If Restock < ReorderAmount Then
MsgBox "Stock is Low"
Else
End If

End Sub
```

Second attempt that I tried

```
Private Sub cboTransactionItem_AfterUpdate()

Dim Restock As Variant
Dim ReorderAmount As Variant

ReorderAmount = DLookup("'[Reorder Amount]'", "ReorderingStock", "[Transaction Item] = '" & Me!cboTransactionItem.Value & "'")
Restock = DLookup([True Stock], "ReorderingStock", "[Transaction Item] = '" & Me!cboTransactionItem.Value & "'")

If Restock < ReorderAmount Then
MsgBox "Stock is Low"
Else
End If

End Sub
```

None of these are working if someone could help I would appreciate it...

Comment: Remove the single quotes around your parameters:  Not: "DLookup("'[Reorder Amount]'","   but "DLookup("[Reorder Amount]","

And which line has the error?   Oh, and your second DLOOKUP is missing the Quotes!!

Comment: It errors out saying Run-time error '2471' expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error '[Reorder Amount]'  after correcting your fix thats what showed up

Comment: Nevermind..... Newbie mistake... was mispelling the field name this entire time..... thank you by you pointing that out I went and checked the field name while i was at it

Comment: Also use Option Explicit